# Photoshop plugin options dialog UI

Tags: c++, photoshop

Im writting a fileformat plugin for photoshop and I need to popup a window with options on load and save such as checkboxes comboboxes etc, how would I do this?

Comment: Is your question how to popup a window with options, or is your question how to popup a window with options *in a fileformat plugin* ?

Answer (score 1):

The latest [SDK from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/) has a number of examples of using dialogs and windows.

On the `Save` or `Save As` options, your plugin needs to handle the `formatSelectorOptionsStart` param and open your options dialog in that code block.

On the `Open` action, there's no normal way to prompt for options (what kind of options would you prompt for?) but the events you could display dialogs from include: `formatSelectorFilterFile`, `formatSelectorReadPrepare`, `formatSelectorReadStart`, `formatSelectorReadContinue`, and `formatSelectorReadFinish`

Here is an example entry point to your plugin that handles the different selectors:

```
DLLExport MACPASCAL void PluginMain(
  const int16 selector,
  PIPickerParams* pParams,
  intptr_t * data,
  int16 * result)
{
    switch(selector)
    {
        case formatSelectorAbout:
            // display about dialog
            break;
        case formatSelectorReadPrepare:
            // prepare to read in file - adjust memory
            break;
        case formatSelectorReadStart:
            // begin interaction regarding reading 
            // dialog here if needed
            break;
        case formatSelectorReadContinue:
        case formatSelectorReadFinish:
        case formatSelectorOptionsPrepare:
            // handle each appropriately
            break;
        case formatSelectorOptionsStart:
            // HERE is where you'd open your window
            // with options, etc.
            break;
        // etc.
        // etc.
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: while this helps, it doesn't really answer the question. right now Ive tried QT but cant get it building in visual studio, and MFC/ATL/WTL refuse to work since adobe didn't create the project as an ATL/MFC project so I cant try those.

Comment: You should be able to use ATL/MFC/WTL.  What is preventing using them?